# Traveling by Air with a Large "Husky" Mobile Job Box

Tags: luggage

Good Day ! I would like to know if it is possible or if anybody has already traveled International with a Large 50 Gal "Husky" or similar Mobile Job Box as Luggage. I am traveling from Orlando to Brazil via Copa Airlines and would like to know if it is permitted. I have consulted the airline and all they tell me is that if the dimensions do not exceed the maximum allowance, than it is fine, thus I would like to have a feedback from somebody who has actually done this before. Your replies would be very helpful and highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

According to Copa's [baggage policy](https://www.copaair.com/en/web/us/baggage-policy) between the United States and Brazil and you're traveling economy, you're allowed two checked pieces. Each must weigh 32 kg / 70 lb or less and the total linear dimensions cannot exceed 62 inches / 158 cm.

I randomly chose a Stanley 50 gallon mobile tool chest to check dimensions and weight. Final assembly size is 37.00 x 23.00 x 23.00 inches and weighs 40.625 lb. Because the total linear dimensions is 83 inches, you'll have to pay a $150 oversize bag fee. If you go over the weight limit, you'll get a $250 overweight fee and can only go up to 99 lb / 45 kg.

Note: I found the Husky box you mentioned, "37 in.", and the dimensions are the same as the Stanley one I used as an example.

Comment: Unless the traveler is carrying very light gear inside this case (unlikely), it may be best to contract with Copa to send it by air cargo instead of as checked baggage.